# Read text after last backslash

Tags: powershell

I am would like to read in the text after the last backslash from my text file.  Currently I have:

```
$data=Get-Content "C:\temp\users.txt"
```

The users.txt file contains path from users home directories

```
\\myserver.home.com\users\user1.test
```

How can I pick out the users account (user1.test) name at the end of the line of text so I can use it as a variable?

Answer (score 15):

You can use a simple *regex* to remove everything until and including the last slash:

```
$user = $data -replace '.*\\'
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, worked great, plus I now have a couple of ways of getting the same results.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are dealing with file paths, you can use [GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$data=Get-Content "C:\temp\users.txt"
$name=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($data)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Split and [-1] to get the string after the last backslash:

```
$data = Get-Content "C:\temp\users.txt"
$file = ($data -split '\\')[-1]
```

This uses two backslashes as backslash is a regex special character (escape) so the first slash is escaping the second.

Comment: Thank you Mark, Worked brilliantly

Answer (score 4):

`$HomeDirArray = Get-Content "C:\temp\users.txt" | Split-Path -Leaf` will give you an array that can be iterated through using `ForEach` (e.g., `ForEach ($User in $HomeDirArray) {...}`.